# CSS Border Shorthand for everything except top

Tags: css

I have a pretty easy questions... Is there shorthand to write the below CSS?

```
border-left:1px solid #818386;
border-right:1px solid #818386;
border-bottom:1px solid #818386;
```

I want the same border for everything except the top??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

CSS

```
border: solid 1px #CCC;
border-top: none;
```

Comment: you can also specify `border-top: 0;` instead of `none`

Comment: It's worth noting that `none` belongs to `border-top-style` while `0` refers to `border-top-width`

Comment: Thanks for the reply i will accept the answer as soon as SO allows me too, missed the obvious on this but thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Remember that CSS is processed top to bottom... so if a style is repeated underneath another style, and there is a conflict, the bottom style will be rendered.

Answer (score 4):

'Shortened'

```
border: 1px solid #818386;
border-top: 0 none;
```

Here you go, i hope this helps you, but that is the must have.

Comment: Wow completely overlooked that thanks everybody for pointing out the obvious

Answer (score 3):

Use `border: 1px solid #818386` the set the `border-top` to `0px`.